# Why is there `sleep infinity` in the kubernetes yaml file for spark

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, minikube

I am reading [this blog](http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/scaling-spark-with-kubernetes-part-6/) and tried to run the [code](https://github.com/phatak-dev/kubernetes-spark). If `sleep infinity` is removed, the pod will be stuck in CrashLoopBackOff:

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                            READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-715509916-zggtc    0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          3m
spark-worker-3468022965-xb5mw   0/1       Completed          5          3m
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the pod goes into the `CrashLoopBackOff` state is that Kubernetes expects to process manage the command executed by the container. Presumably the `start-master.sh` script executes, then exits, which Kubernetes interprets as the process dying. You need to execute a command which will not exit in order to keep the pod alive. In this case the `sleep infinity` is included to simulate a long running process. You could also achieve this with something like:

`'./start-master.sh ; /bin/bash'`

Comment: Thanks how about this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596146/why-my-spark-job-stuck-in-kafka-streaming?

Answer (score 0):

yes, since you removed the sleep infinity, container is starting and terminating. you need to keep sleep statement.  Is there a reason you want to remove sleep?

Thanks
SR

Comment: the `sleep infinity` is reason for the problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596146/why-my-spark-job-stuck-in-kafka-streaming?